# Is there an acceptable Linux targeted GUI client for git-svn?

Tags: linux, git, version-control, git-svn

My employer uses subversion for version-control, and this is unlikely to change. I'm interested in learning more about git, and using git-svn to interface with my employer's subversion repositories. My question is: if I were to begin using git-svn, would I need to do some or all of my version control work from the command-line? Or is there a (linux) GUI client that can perform all the git-svn-related tasks that I will need?

Update: Based on the answers so far, there doesn't appear to be a GUI client for git-svn. However, I would like to call attention to [this feature request](http://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=566293) for the Giggle GUI client as proof that there is some interest in a feature like this. Hopefully a positive answer to this question can be added sometime in the coming months. (In fact, I think that in the near future, the best way to interact with subversion might be to use a GUI client for git!)

Update 2: The recently released 2.1 version of SmartGit does fully support Git/SVN integration. This proves that there is at least one GUI client allowing Git and SVN to be used together. There may be more.

Comment: I urge you to reconsider the idea that there being no gui for git-svn is the answer to your question. Years have passed. http://www.syntevo.com/git-svn/index.html; and in the non-linux world: http://www.git-tower.com/ http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This page](http://www.syntevo.com/git-svn/index.html) seems to indicate that [SmartGit](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgit/index.html) can do what you want. As far as I can tell, you have to do the initial init/clone from cmd/bash though.

Comment: Now that some time has passed, I have changed the accepted answer, as suggested by dlamblin in a comment for the original question. SmartGit does seem to do the trick, and there are some other options listed in that comment that interested people may want to check out.

Comment: unfortunately SmartGit removed the supprot for git-svn in its latest versions and the last version that still works with git-svn will stop working on Jan 28th

Answer (score 8):

There is no gui client for Git-SVN; so you will have to use the command line to use Git-svn.   Fortunately, you don't have to learn much to work git-svn.  Some resources, from simple to detailed:

- [Learning git-svn in 5min](http://tsunanet.blogspot.com/2007/07/learning-git-svn-in-5min.html)
- [Git - SVN Crash Course](http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html)
- [Introduction to git-svn for Subversion/SVK users and deserters](http://utsl.gen.nz/talks/git-svn/intro.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any GUI client for Git that you want to use. You only have to revert to the command line when you want to interface with the Subversion server (e.g. for committing and updating).

Comment: So there are some things that would require the command-line? There are no GUI clients for git that can commit to the subversion server?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it would be possible to somehow intercept the Push command in git-gui and make it run git-svn dcommit instead? I have already added an git alias to run !git-svn dcommit.