# Is there a git-svn windows client something like TortoiseSVN?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn, git-svn

I like TortoiseSVN's Windows integration. Is there something like that for dealing with git-svn? I'd even go with a less integrated GUI if it is quick enough to access. What I don't want is a CLI as I rarely would have a command prompt sitting in the correct directory.

---

[This is a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371682/is-there-an-acceptable-gui-client-for-git-svn) but for Linux

Comment: @BuhakeSindi: that question was removed from SO...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have a look at [TortoiseGit](https://tortoisegit.org/) which is a TortoiseSVN clone for Git.

Comment: Does TortoiseGit support the git-svn tools?

Comment: Oh, Foo. It seem that TortoiseGit doesn't have hooks into git-svn :( at least not that I can find)

Comment: Great tool. For me I wanted to view changes over Samba before commit/push. TortoiseGit does allow you to view all changes and diff across a mapped Samba drive which is pretty damn cool.

Comment: Does TortoiseGit support git-svn, or just git?

Comment: It does!! I started using it :)

Answer (score 32):

TortoiseGit (https://tortoisegit.org/) added basic support for git-svn in release 0.8.1.0:

The release log says:

*Add Basic Git-SVN Operation:*

- Add SVN DCommit Command
- Add "SVN Rebase" and "SVN DCommit"
  command at shell contextmenu
- Support Git svn-clone at clone
  dialog.

Comment: It totally works.
you have check the use svn repository and possibly specify username so it prompts for password.... but it works.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way I found was to use the `git gui`, and add a `git svn dcommit` and `git svn rebase` command to the Tools menu.

If you install msysGit, it will even put a 'Git GUI here' command in your context menu.

This has the advantage of not requiring any additional software apart from git itself, and will work on every platform that git (gui) runs on.

**Edit:** I should mention that this is exactly the way I have been productively using git against our svn-repos for a few months now. Works just fine. And it's the same on Windows, Linux, whatever. So no need to use different tools for the same job, depending on the OS.

Comment: What tools menu? Do you known of any docs that explain what that is and how to do it?

Comment: I guess the menu only shows up once you open an existing repo. So at least for the initial git svn clone you would have to use the commandline. Once this is there, you open it with git gui, and use the Tools menu. The day-to-day update/commit cycle can then be done entirely from the gui.

Comment: Brilliant!  Automated way to add them to menu: `git config --global --replace-all 'guitool.git svn rebase.cmd' 'git svn rebase'; git config --global --replace-all 'guitool.git svn dcommit.cmd' 'git svn dcommit'`

Answer (score 6):

Try SmartGit , it has almost all the functions console has and it has great GUI. http://www.syntevo.com/index.html

Answer (score 2):

A sideways and very late answer, but maybe useful to later spectators, re why you don't want a CLI; assuming you're using XP install the Microsoft [Command Prompt Here Powertoy](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx) which gives you an Explorer right-click shortcut on a folder. I use it all the time.
Windows 7 has the feature out of the box, but you have to hold down some key while you right click, I think.. shift or alt or something.

Also, Tortoisegit now apparently has git-svn features, I am going to check them out..

Comment: Option 1: `Right-click, command-prompt-here, git ...` Option 2: `Right-click, git command`. Well, that's better than nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The best GUI tool for for using git local and svn as a server is [SmartGitHg](http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/) from syntevo (works for Windows, Lunux and OS X). For OS X you cal also use [SourceTree](http://sourcetreeapp.com/) from Atlassian. Windows Version of SourceTree doesn't support SVN.

Comment: Looks like version 1.4 (release January 2014) brought support for git-svn on Windows: http://blog.sourcetreeapp.com/2014/01/29/sourcetree-for-windows-1-4-released/

Comment: Yes. Sourcetree now supports SVN bridge too. I tested this several time (because I love Sourcetree under OS X) since the first beta support on Windows but this is very unstable. I had a lot of problems with big repositioreis (we have over 1GB). SmartGitHg works here without any problem. Perhaps it will be better in the future (or we switch to Git-Server ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

[You can use TortoiseSVN itself](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support). That's what I do.

Comment: This is applicable only to GitHub, other git servers do not support this.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429834/git-hash-to-svn-number-generation-scheme

Answer (score 0):

One may use any Git client while using the server-side Git-SVN synchronization setup. Have a look at [SubGit](http://subgit.com) to achieve that.

One has to install SubGit into Subversion repository:

```
$ subgit configure $SVN_REPOS
# Adjust $SVN_REPOS/conf/subgit.conf to specify your branches and tags
# Adjust $SVN_REPOS/conf/authors.txt to specify git & svn authors mapping
$ subgit install $SVN_REPOS
...
$ INSTALLATION SUCCESSFUL
```

SubGit converts Subversion repository into Git (it works in opposite direction as well) and installs SVN and Git hooks. These hooks are triggered by `svn commit` and `git push` as result all incoming modifications are instantly replicated to Git or SVN correspondingly. For more details please refer to [SubGit documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation) and [git-svn](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html) comparison.

Starting from version 2.0 (not yet released at the moment of posting) SubGit allows to synchronized Subversion and Git repositories located on different hosts.

SubGit is a commercial tool. It is free for open-source, academic and small projects (up to 10 committers).

Full disclosure: I'm one of SubGit developers.

Answer (score -2):

I have not seen best tool in past related to SVN like gui, but Git has now made something very useful and easy try Git Desktop for windows:
https://desktop.github.com/

Comment: How does this answer the quesion of a UI that works with Git-SVN (I don't see anything indicating that Git Desktop supports that).