# create local branch in svn like git

Tags: git, svn, tortoisesvn

In git when I want to fix something or create new feature I am adding new local branch, apply  the changes that need and then merge it to master branch and push it, but I SVN I can't create local branch, apparently when I want new feature branch I have to do `svn update` in Tortoise application, after that I can see new branch but it push this new branch to the server But I just want local branch to remove it after fixing my issues.
does its might to create local branch without pushing it to the server?

Comment: There's no such thing as "local branch" in svn.

Comment: You can't. SVN works in a very different way. If you'd like to create local branches, then use Git. After the code is prepared, you can apply these changes to an SVN repository.

Comment: What is the problem with creating a "normal" SVN branch? `svn update` does not commit anything to the server.

Answer (score 2):

Use `git svn clone`, then **you can use any git features**, including the local branch feature you want to use.

Use `git svn fetch` or `git svn rebase` for something like `svn update`.

Use `git svn dcommit` to commit your changes back to svn repository when everything is ready.

Also see [my answer for the question: how to convert svn repository to git on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761086/how-to-convert-svn-repository-to-git-on-windows/46597922#46597922) and read [Pro Git v2 - Chapter 9](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Git-as-a-Client) for more information and examples.