# How to use git (on windows) to contribute code to svn?

Tags: git, svn

I wish to contribute code to http://svn.r-project.org/R/ 
But I only have experience with using git (through a windows GUI), and no experience with SVN.

I see from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/894402/256662), that it is possible to:

> The easiest way I found was to use the git gui, and add a git svn
>   dcommit and git svn rebase command to the Tools menu.
>
> If you install msysGit, it will even put a 'Git GUI here' command in
>   your context menu.
>
> This has the advantage of not requiring any additional software apart
>   from git itself, and will work on every platform that git (gui) runs
>   on.

However, it also says:

> I guess the menu only shows up once you open an existing repo. So at least for the initial git svn clone you would have to use the commandline.

Can someone please instruct me on how to get this step done? (or of a different solution, if there is a simple one for that)

Comment: Git -> SVN is a bad idea. It works, but it work not good. You should learn how to use SVN, it is not that hard.

Comment: Thank you TIM.  All my needs are to make simple commit to a remote server - do you think that would be "too much" for the current bridges between the two?

Comment: Basic committing should work. I am however sure you'll need more commands lateron.

Comment: @TimWolla: I haven't seen such a bad and useless comment from you since a long time. `git-svn` is perfectly fine if you *have* to work with a SVN repository on the remote side and cannot change it. Why would you use an inferior client (svn) if you can have the full power of git? Yes, SVN is very easy to use but if you are used to Git you are likely to hate having to use SVN.

Comment: @ThiefMaster I had several problems with git-svn. Or maybe I wasn't using it correctly.

Comment: TortoiseSVN provides a gui-based subversion client integrated into Windows Explorer. Its extremely easy to install and to use.  After installation, just go into Windows Explorer and right click.

Comment: Dear Grothendieck - I have already done that.  What menu system do I work with now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this tutorial may be helpful to you:

http://trac.parrot.org/parrot/wiki/git-svn-tutorial