# git hash to svn number generation scheme

Tags: git, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Recently I have find out that TortoiseSVN (surprise, surprise) supports git.
So you can just checkout git repository using TortoiseSVN, and even to reference external git repositories. On internet there exists huge amount of questions & threads on how to get good numbering scheme from git hash, which is found many times as too cryptic and difficult to use.

For example: [How to get the git commit count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677436/how-to-get-the-git-commit-count).

By following this [link: Is there a git-svn windows client something like TortoiseSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894360/is-there-a-git-svn-windows-client-something-like-tortoisesvn), I find out that git support was wired under svn long time ago:

- [Announcing SVN Support](https://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support)
- [Improved Subversion Client Support](https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support)

Can you tell me what kind of scheme TortoiseSVN uses to display svn numbers?

- Are those numbers unique if commit is done from git ?
- Are those numbers unique if commit is done from TortoiseSvn ?

What kind of scheme TortoiseSVN uses to map git hash to svn revision number ?

Comment: Git? GitHub maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseSVN does not support Git.

I guess that you tried GitHub repositories with TortoiseSVN. Yes, it works in general and should also work with any other SVN client. GitHub allows SVN clients perform simple operations with its repositories through a special transparent proxy (I may be wrong, but that's what I read). So it is not TortoiseSVN that uses a special mapping schema, it's GitHub that reports Git revisions to SVN client in a form that the client can digest. :)

There is another Tortoise* client -- TortoiseGit. It takes Windows Shell integration idea and *tries* to map it to Git commands.

Comment: Is github's transparent proxy available from somewhere to download ?

Comment: @TarmoPikaro I don’t think so. However, it could be included with GitHub Enterprise, though. I don’t know for sure.